# Cannot edit tags of question that has only 1 tag

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I'm trying to edit the tags of this question:

[Formatting web page with Back end data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377810/formatting-web-page-with-back-end-data/)

The link to do so is not appearing...

Any ideas?

Comment: It had an edit awaiting approval, I just approved it; how's that now? Otherwise, it's now allowing me into the editor.

Comment: OK. I understand why the link to edit the tags was not showing up: the question had and edit in the queue.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: I wrote the above comment before seeing your comment... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't see the edit link, and you don't have the reputation required to edit questions or answers without that your edit gets reviewed, it usually means there is already a pending edit that needs to be approved.